# Xamarin Scroll lagging in WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So i injected some java script in my webview and on scroll event i call the nativ function on cs.

The problem is that the scroll function is lagging for some reasion even though i have it inside `setTimeout` event.

Any idee on how to solve it?

Obbs the scroll work just fine when i remove the code below.

Here is the js function

```
script.Append(@"var timer; window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
                if (timer)
                    clearTimeout(timer);

                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                if (window.toBottom === true){
                    window.toBottom = false;
                    Native('onScroll', window.scrollY);
                    return;
                }

                if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight -30)) {
                        Native('onScrolledBottomReached', window.scrollY);
                    }else if (window.scrollY<=5) {
                         Native('OnScrolledTopReached', window.scrollY);
                    }else {
                         Native('onScroll', window.scrollY);
                          }
                },1000);
                 });");
```

Comment: Have you tried to set  WebView's layer type ?like `webView.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);`

Comment: im using XLabs.Forms.Controls.HybridWebView and it dose not have SetlayerType